# How to change user input value as default for future use?

Tags: swift

I tried to write a simple app to calculate the finish date for project based on the input of how much minutes user has already finished:

```
@IBOutlet weak var BDDate: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var BDTime: NSTextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    }
}

@IBAction func BDSave(_ sender: Any) {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let daysToAdd = 10 - Int(BDTime.stringValue)!

    var dateComponent = DateComponents()
    dateComponent.day = daysToAdd

    let BDFinish = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: dateComponent, to: currentDate)

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM, dd"
    BDDate.stringValue = formatter.string(from: BDFinish!)
    }
```

However since it might take multiple days to finish so there'll be multiple inputs. I am wondering if it's possible to save previous inputs as default so that the finish date will reflect the true date after accumulated previous inputs.

For example, if the whole project takes 10 hours to finish, planning one hour per day, the final result will be 9 days later if I input 1 hour today. However when I open the app again and input another 1 hour tomorrow, the final result will still be 9 days later instead of 8 days later.

Appreciate any guidance or suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UserDefaults which will persist a value between app loads, for example:

```
    var daysRemaining = 10 //For new project

    //If there is an existing value, load it from UserDefaults
    if let savedDaysRemaining = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "savedDaysRemaining") as? Int {
        daysRemaining = savedDaysRemaining
    }

    //Substract the number of new days
    let daysToSubtract = 1
    daysRemaining -= daysToSubtract

    //Save new value to User Defaults
    UserDefaults.standard.set(daysRemaining, forKey: "savedDaysRemaining")
```